# Cannot see stylesheet effect in JavaFX Scene Builder?

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

Q1. I've set the background image for my **BorderPane** using a CSS stylesheet(style.css).

When I run the application, the background works, but I'm not able to see the background while working in Scene Builder. Why is that?

CSS code:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-image: url("grey.jpg");
}
```

Q2. Also how can I achieve this with just setting the style for **BorderPane** instead of using a stylesheet? I've tried:

[image]

But that doesn't change the background while running the app or in Scene Builder.